# SAPUI5 Bullet Chart Missing Themes

Tags: css, charts, graphviz, sapui5

When I use the viz frame to display a bullet chart:

api: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame.html ex: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Bullet/preview

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
   src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
   data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.viz, sap.m, sap.ui.ux3"
   data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
</script>

var oBulletChart = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame({
  'uiConfig' : {
    'applicationSet': 'fiori'
  },
  'vizType'  : 'bullet',
  'width'    : '600px',
  'height'   : '600px',
});
```

I get the following bullet chart, correctly themed:

[image]

else when I use the standard (which I would highly prefer because of the loading time) I get the chart with a wrong theming:

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.viz, sap.m, sap.ui.ux3"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
</script>
```

[image]

So, the problem is CSS, but how would I fix this issue? SAPUI5 Version pulled from Backend is 1.22 (Bullet Chart needs 1.21, viz Frame needs 1.22) .. Hana Site probably is 1.23?

I think it is about the "fiori" theming thing, but I need it to display green/red values dynamically, in the wrong version everything is black by default.

Is it possible to pull this missing theme?

Additional Infos:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js --> Timestamp: * Date: 2014-05-01T17:42Z
local /resources/sap-ui-core.js --> Timestamp: * Date: 2013-07-03T13:48Z

Which SAP UI component has to be upgraded to increase the system version?

**Edit 1:**

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/viz/ui5/controls/css/controls.css
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/viz/ui5/controls/libs/css/sap.viz.controls.css
--> not loaded in HANA, loaded in local libraries
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/themes/sap_goldreflection/library.css
--> smaller in hana version
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/unified/themes/sap_goldreflection/library.css
--> bigger in hana version

Answer (score 2):

The UI5 version can be checked by `sap.ui.version` in the browser console or by pressing `Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S` in any UI5 app (open top panel in the popup). This shows sapui5.hana.ondemand.com is version:
`Core Version   1.24.3 (built at 201410291107)`, so I'm not sure what your timestamp from May means. Please check your UI5 version the same way.

Without a running example I can't say much, but this looks like the base theme being loaded as a fallback. Is there a 404 response for a CSS file request? Or are the local library.css files significantly smaller than the HANA ones? (~half the size)? 
What platform are you running on? (ABAP? Java? Web server? Did you install UI5 on your own or do you use the version that was shipped with it? - this answer decides whether there can be a server-side theme fallback mechanism and also is a required information for the upgrade question.

Comment: thanks, good hint with sap.ui.version. I add some differences I found.

Comment: I think we are going for EHP7 soon, this hopefully fixes my issue. But for me its importing to find the difference, why the themning in my version does not work, how may I find this?